# Are there any native controls for usage in a C++ Windows Store application?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, controls

I was looking for a data grid control to use in a Windows Store application written in C++.

So I've tried a couple of vendors' package selling controls for WinRT and as incredible as this can be, **none** of them can be used in a C++ Windows Store application ...

I've tried the packages of :

- [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinRT/)
- [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/overview.aspx#native-windows-8.1-controls)
- [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-ui/)
- [Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt)

Did I miss something or the only available ones are from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465351.aspx) ?

Comment: So long as you have the source code for the controls, you should at least be able to reuse the Styles and Templates for them. I'm not sure if the Codebehind will work for them though, I believe it matters whether or not it's compiled as a Runtime Component or Class Library. If I'm not mistaken, it must be built as a Runtime Component to be cross-compatible with C++, but I'd double check that. If they give you the source code, you may be able to create a Runtime Component which includes the control. Also, check out [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the point was to use controls rather than coding ones, I think I have found a partial answer to why there aren't controls for C++ in here : http://blogs.telerik.com/georgiatanasov/posts/12-07-27/consuming-radcontrols-for-metro-xaml-from-c.aspx

Comment: About halfway down, he mentions what I suggested, create a Runtime Component. Apparently, you can just *reference* the Class Library they have created without having to do any of the implementation yourself and it will still have access to it, which is much easier than I thought it would be, and won't require you to re-implement anything.

Comment: Yes I've seen that, will give it a try. Thanks for the heads up.